# C#: access cache variables in .ashx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can one access cache objects in handler class?

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    //Cache["asd"] = "asd";
    //context.Response["1"]="sfd";
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    string ss=(string)context.Cache["aasd"];
    string sss=(string)context.Session["sdf"];
}
```

Comment: Actually i intend to access objects of 
System.Web.Caching

Comment: is it the same? context and web.caching?

Comment: Ok got it ... HttpRuntime/HttpContext cache access the System.Web.Caching which is global... am i rught here?

Answer (score 4):

`context.Cache` should work. To use `context.Session` you should mark the handler to require session state by implementing the `IRequiresSessionState` marker interface.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use context.Cache, if not you can always use HttpRuntime.Cache (which is what HttpContext.Cache uses internally anyway)